# Hangouts SMS: Keep same conversation when contact gets a new phone number

Tags: google-hangouts

I'm using Hangouts and a contact recently changed her phone number. Now I have one conversation with her old number and one with her name on it in my Hangouts. Is there any way to merge these conversations?

I'd prefer not to continue to have both numbers under the one contact for fear of accidentally dialing the old number!

Comment: Without merging the contact info, I don't think this is doable. Hangouts doesn't have the ability to merge conversations in an ad-hoc manner or anything like that, it just organizes them by contact.

Comment: Try going in the chat list and hold on first conversation then select second one, if you now have a menu with merge option you are done. It doesn't work all the times it might be related to the presence of gmail account in both conversations. Worth a try.

Comment: Why not merge the contact, and make the new number the default one? Or change the old number (once merged) with an error (an extra digit or an `*` at the start or something) in it so you can't dial it by mistake? No point in making this complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to merge the two conversations in Hangouts is to update/merge the contacts under your Google account - http://www.google.com/contacts